# Why is the "DisplayName" missing when getting the bucket ACL using s3api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get the display name of the owner of a bucket using the following command:

```sh
$ aws --profile <profile> s3api get-bucket-acl --bucket <bucket-name>
```

The response I get back is:

```json
{
    "Owner": {
        "ID": "b<long-id>e"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "ID": "b<long-id>e",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        }
    ]
}
```

According to [AWS s3api get-bucket-acl documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/get-bucket-acl.html) the response should include the `"DisplayName"` such as:

```json
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "my-username",
        "ID": "7009a8971cd538e11f6b6606438875e7c86c5b672f46db45460ddcd087d36c32"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "my-username",
                "ID": "7009a8971cd538e11f6b6606438875e7c86c5b672f46db45460ddcd087d36c32"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        }
    ]
}
```

Why don't I get the `"DisplayName"` back?

Note: The `aws` version I am using is `aws-cli/2.4.25 Python/3.8.8 Darwin/20.6.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off`

Comment: I can confirm this problem, the response doesn't match the API docs.

Comment: What is your actual goal? Why do you want to know the 'owner' of an object? These days, ACLs are best ignored and permissions should be granted via IAM Policies or Bucket Policies.

Comment: Well according to this [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=241134), someone in 2021 (keyword masterofpuppets) confirmed they were unable to change their account display name from years ago. So when your `DisplayName` is not available, maybe it was just not set when the root user created the account?

Comment: From my testing it looks like this is a regional issue. For buckets in us-east-1 or eu-west-1 the info is returned, for a bucket in eu-central-1 it isn't. No matter which API endpoint I'm using. I created a support case, now I'm curious.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I just wanted to put a face/name/host/machine behind an obscure Owner.ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with AWS Support on this and according to the service team you can't rely on this information being present in all regions.

Apparently, this data is only returned in the regions that also [return e-mail-addresses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Grantee.html#API_Grantee_Contents).

> **Note**
>
> Using email addresses to specify a grantee is only supported in the
> following AWS Regions:
>
> - US East (N. Virginia)
> - US West (N. California)
> - US West (Oregon)
> - Asia Pacific (Singapore)
> - Asia Pacific (Sydney)
> - Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
> - Europe (Ireland)
> - South America (São Paulo)